# How to input an array parameter of values to Firebird Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, arrays, parameters, firebird

I would like to input an **array parameter** of IDs to **Firebird Stored Procedure**.

:INPUT_LIST_ID = [1, 2, 12, 45, 75, 45]

I'm need to execute this SQL command:

```
SELECT *
FROM CITY
WHERE ID_CITY IN (:INPUT_LIST_ID)
```

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CITY
WHERE ID_CITY IN (SELECT ID FROM GetIntegerList('1, 2, 12, 45, 75, 45'))
```

You would have to create a new Firebird Procedure called "GetIntegerList" which would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE "GETINTEGERLIST"("AINTEGERLIST" VARCHAR(32000))
returns (
  ID integer
)
as
  declare variable IntegerList varchar(32000);
  declare variable CommaPos integer;
  declare variable IntegerVal varchar(10);
begin
  IntegerList = AIntegerList || ' ';
  CommaPos = Position(',', IntegerList);

  while (CommaPos > 0) do
  begin
    IntegerVal = Trim(SubString(IntegerList from 1 for CommaPos - 1));

    if (Char_Length(IntegerVal) > 0) then
    begin
      if (IntegerVal similar to '[0-9]*') then
      begin
        ID = Cast(IntegerVal as integer);
        suspend;
      end
    end

    if (Char_Length(IntegerList) > CommaPos) then
      IntegerList = SubString(IntegerList from CommaPos + 1);
    else
      IntegerList = '';

    CommaPos = Position(',', IntegerList);
  end

  IntegerList = Trim(IntegerList);

  if (Char_Length(IntegerList) > 0) then
  begin
    if (IntegerList similar to '[0-9]*') then
    begin
      ID = Cast(IntegerList as integer);
      suspend;
    end
  end
end
```

Note, this was done in Firebird 2.5.2.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK no, thats not possible. While Firebird does have array data type, support for it is rudimentary and use of arrays is generally not recommended. I think the easiest solution would be to pass the array as (comma separated) string and then use the [`for execute statement`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html#langrefupd25-psql-execstat-multirow) statement to get the resultset, something like

```
create procedure CITY (INPUT_LIST_ID varchar(1024)) 
returns( ... )
as
begin
  for execute statement
    'select ... from T where ID_CITY IN ('|| INPUT_LIST_ID ||')' into ...
  do begin
     suspend;
  end
end
```

This means however that the statement you use to get the result also changes, instead of `WHERE` you would use the parameter of the stored procedure `CITY`:

```
SELECT * FROM CITY('1, 2, 12, 45, 75, 45')
```

Another option to send the parameter list is to use [global temporary table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html). This has the pro that you can send huge number of IDs without exceeding the maximum allowed statements size but it is more work to set up the call...

```
create global temporary table SP_CITY_PARAMS (
  id int not null primary key
)
on commit delete rows;

create procedure CITY
returns( ... )
as
begin
  for select ... from T where ID_CITY IN (
      select id from SP_CITY_PARAMS
  ) into ...
  do begin
     suspend;
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it works, but I have more then 10000 cities in my database.

Comment: @dataol Do you want to pass them all? Why not just join on the table containing these cities?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not all, just the selected records. But an user can select 1 or 10.000 cities.

Comment: @dataol Consider using a [global temporary table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html), insert the selected cities, join against that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM CITY
    WHERE '/city1/city2/city.../' containing '/' || ID_CITY || '/';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firebird 1.5 (It should work on higher versions too), you can use this simple function i made to convert a single string into an integer array:

```
create or alter procedure INTEGER_LIST (
    input varchar(4096))
returns (
    INT_VALUE integer)
as
declare variable CHAR_COUNT integer;
declare variable PARAM_LENGTH integer;
declare variable READ_VALUE char(1);
declare variable CURRENT_INTEGER varchar(20);
begin
    param_length = strlen(input);
    char_count = 0;
    current_integer = '';
    while (char_count < param_length) do begin
        char_count = :char_count + 1;
        read_value = substr(:input, :char_count, :char_count);
        if (:read_value <> ',') then begin
            current_integer = :current_integer || :read_value;
        end else if (:read_value <> ' ') then  begin
            int_value = cast(:current_integer as integer);
            current_integer = '';
            suspend;
        end

        if (:char_count = :param_length) then begin
            int_value = cast(:current_integer as integer);
            suspend;
        end
    end
end
```

**Usage**

`select int_value from integer_list('1,2,3,4, 5, 200, 1, 598415, 2')`

Will return this:

```
INT_VALUE
1
2
3
4
5
200
1
598415
2
```

Comment: It is nice, thank you! But it works only with short strings (like 50 chars), and crashes on long ones =(((( Can you help me in this case please?

Comment: Sorry but fortunately I don't work with firebird anymore, but it should work regardless of string length, what problem did you find?