# How to pass multiple values in a single parameter if number of values is not predefined

Tags: delphi, firebird

I select some rows in dbgrid and then have to pass set of values in parameter of stored procedure or query. I use Firebird 3. How to pass multiple values in a single parameter if number of values is not predefined? For example, for 3 values of good_id I get error:

> conversion error from string "7802 ,8403 ,11461"

```
create or alter procedure sp_goods (id varchar(60))
returns (
    good varchar(50),
    good_id integer)
as
begin
 for select good_id, good from goods where good_id in (:id)
 into :good_id, :good
 do suspend;
end


 procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
       str : String;  
       i  : Integer;      
     begin
     Query1.Close;
     Query1.SQL.Text := 'select * from sp_goods(:id) ';
    
     with DBGridGoods do
       begin
        if SelectedRows.Count > 0 then
          begin
             str := '';
             With DataSource.DataSet do
             for i := 0 to SelectedRows.Count - 1 do
             begin
                GotoBookmark(SelectedRows.Items[i]) ;
                str := str + FieldByName('good_id').asString + ', ';
             end;
          str := copy( str, 1, length( str ) - 2 );
          end;
       end;
    
     Query1.Params[0].AsString:=str;
     Query1.Open;
```

end;

If I call stored procedure in IBExpert

```
select * from sp_goods('8403')
```

It works, but

```
select * from sp_goods('8403','7802')
```

returns error

> Input parameter mismatch for procedure sp_goods.

The same error occurs if I use query instead of stored procedure.

I tried to use array for values, but get empty dataset:

```
 procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   a: array of integer;
 begin
  Query1.Close;
  Query1.SQL.Text := 'select * from sp_goods(:id) ';
        
  setlength(a, 2);
  a[0]:= 7802;
  a[1]:=8403;
  Query1.Params[0].Value:= a;   
  Query1.Open;
end;
```

Comment: Use an array parameter?

Comment: Which database are you using?  You can create parameters at runtime...

Comment: @JohnEasley Firebird 3.

Comment: @RonMaupin Array support in Firebird is extremely limited, and doesn't work here.

Comment: Have you tried joining your stored procedure to a query that produces the necessary IDs?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I never used such join. 
I dont know how join query and sp in my case. Real query or sp looks like this: 
SELECT  . . . FROM Goods g LEFT JOIN  (select  . . .   from(  select  . . .   from table1    group by Good_id    union all  select  . . .   from table2   group by Good_id  union all   select  . . .  from table3  group by Good_id ) dt1    group by Good_id ) dt2 on g.good_id=dt2.good_id

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  My aim is multiselect some rows from query (goods turns) with ctrl+mouse combination and show only these goods turns( incomes and sales) and print it.  As I realize I must multiselect rows with double clicking on dbgrid's rows and insert these rows in other clientdataset.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841167/how-to-input-an-array-parameter-of-values-to-firebird-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pass set of values into single parameter in Firebird.

In your example whole stored procedure is meaningless and it is simpler and faster to select all values at once into original grid using join. If you wish to get goods for selected items only and to put them into a separate grid the best way is to perform the query in your loop instead of gathering list of ids. If you prepare the query once (it is a common mistake to do prepare() call inside of the loop) it will be quite fast.

Comment: user13964273,  which join are you talk about? Can you give an example? 
My aim is multiselect some rows from query (goods turns) with ctrl+mouse combination and show only these goods turns( incomes and sales) and print it. As I realize I must multiselect rows with double clicking on dbgrid's rows and insert these rows in other clientdataset.

Comment: @basti "Other clientset" is not necessary. There are grids that can display data directly. TStringGrid, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in two ways in the past.  One is by using **Dynamic Queries**, which is not what you want to do, unless there is no other option.

The other way is by using this procedure.  **I am dragging this from my archives, and there will be other ways to achieve this more efficiently.  I am providing it to show how to do it.**

```sql
create or alter procedure "Split_Line"
(  IP_NOTE VARCHAR (16000),
   IP_SEP CHAR (1))
returns (
   "Index" INTEGER,
   "Line" VARCHAR (16000))
as
  declare variable lLines varchar (16000);
  declare variable lMax   integer;
  declare variable lPos   integer;
begin
  lMax   = 16000;
  lLines = ip_Note;
  "Index" = 0;
  while (lLines is not null)
  do begin
     "Line" = null;
     lPos   = null;
     select "Result" from "Pos" (:Ip_Sep, :lLines) into :lPos;
     if (lPos is null or lPos = 0)
     then begin
          /* Last line with no separator */
          "Line" = lLines;
          lLines = null;
     end
     else if (lPos = 1 and lLines = Ip_Sep)
     then begin
          /* Last char is a separator */
          "Line" = '';
          lLines = null;
     end
     else begin
          /* Normal Case */
//          "Line" = "SubStr" (:lLines, 1, :lPos-1);
//          lLines = "SubStr" (:lLines, :lPos+1, :lMax);
          "Line" = substring (:lLines from 1 for :lPos-1);
          lLines = substring (:lLines from :lPos+1 for :lMax);

     end
     "Index" = "Index" + 1;
     suspend;
  end
end
```

You call it with a comma separated values in a string and the separator character (comma in this case).  And it returns a table that you use.

Example of usage

```sql
select * from "Split_Line" ('x,a,cat', ',')
```

will return

| Index | Line |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | cat |

And you can use it in your case

```sql
create or alter procedure sp_goods (id varchar(60))
returns (
    good varchar(50),
    good_id integer)
as
begin
 for select good_id, good from goods 
 where good_id in (select cast("Line" as numeric (18, 0)) 
                   from "Split_Line" (:id, ','))
 into :good_id, :good
 do suspend;
end
```

Supporting procedure to compile before **Split_String**

```sql
create or alter procedure "Pos"
(  SUBSTR VARCHAR (100),
   STR VARCHAR (16000))
returns (  "Result" INTEGER)
as
  DECLARE VARIABLE SubStr2 VARCHAR(16256); /* 1 + SubStr-lenght + Str-length */
  DECLARE VARIABLE Tmp VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN
  IF (SubStr IS NULL OR Str IS NULL)
  THEN BEGIN
       "Result" = NULL;
       suspend;
       EXIT;
  END
  IF (SubStr = '' OR Str = '')
  THEN BEGIN
       "Result" = 0;
       suspend;
       EXIT;
  END

  SubStr2 = SubStr || '%';
  Tmp = '';
  "Result" = 1;
  WHILE (Str NOT LIKE SubStr2 AND Str NOT LIKE Tmp)
  DO BEGIN
     SubStr2 = '_' || SubStr2;
     Tmp = Tmp || '_';
     "Result" = "Result" + 1;
  END

  IF (Str LIKE Tmp)
  THEN "Result" = 0;
  suspend;
END
```

And I have replaced my **substr** (from my user defined function library) to use the firebird **substring** in the **Split_Line** procedure.

Apologies for the quoted identifiers, always use **Dialect 3**.  And the odd capitalisation was to support Crystal Reports which at that time would only work with uppercase procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do it is to use **Dynamic Queries**.

```sql
create or alter procedure sp_goods (id varchar(60))
returns (
    good varchar(50),
    good_id integer)
as
 declare lsql varchar (5000);
begin
 lsql = 'select good_id, good from goods where good_id in (' || :id || ')';
 for execute statement lsql  
 into :good_id, :good
 do suspend;
end
```

### Disadvantages

1. Normally, when a procedure is compiled, the queries are prepared at that  time.  So, execution is faster.  With **Dynamic Queries** or **Dynamic Sql**, the query has to be prepared every time the procedure is executed.
2. Normally, when a procedure is compiled, the engine validates the table and fields etc.  In this case the validation happens at execution time.  So you have to be really careful how you construct your query.

**Note** - I havent had time to test it with a real table, but it compiles.  (Its 3am, so I might check that tomorrow).
I wouldn't normally recommend this, but  everything has a place.

Comment: Did the answers work for you